# Window.location not working I have tried eveything

Tags: javascript, window.location

```
/*jslint plusplus: true*/
function signin() {
    'use strict';
    localStorage.setItem("index", 0);
    var get, sn, get1, text, i;
    get = localStorage.getItem("login");
    get1 = JSON.parse(get);
    sn = document.getElementById("studentnumber").value;

    if (sn === get1[0].student) {
        window.alert("Welcome, " + get1[0].fName + get1[0].lName);
        window.location = 'Newsfeed.html';
    } else {
        window.alert = "Sorry Student Number or Password is incorrect! Did up already make an account?";
    }

}
```

The window.location is not working. The page name is right and the program gives the window.alert when the information is correct but it would load to the new page. Anyone know why it doesn't work? Please help! I've been at it for hours.

Comment: shouldn't it be `window.alert("Sorry Student Number or Password is incorrect! Did up already make an account?");`

Comment: @Alon lol! yes you are correct! my mistake I must have missed that.

Comment: @SpiderMonkey does it work now with that revision?

Comment: @NickZuber no even with that edit, the window.load is not working.

Comment: Where is `window.load`? I don't see it anywhere in your question

Comment: i meant window.location sorry!  `window.location = 'Newsfeed.html';`

Comment: what happened when you dismiss the "Welcome " alert?

Comment: @BlackJack the page just refreshes

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debugger? Is it on chrome, firefox, IE?

Comment: you can try full formatted url such as "http://yourdomain/Newsfeed.html" with http:// instead of only "Newsfeed.html"

Comment: @kometen I'm on chrome , and no there are no errors in the debugger.

Comment: if "the page just refreshes" without errors and url hasn't changed - that means you are redirecting to same page

Comment: What's in the url bar after refresh?

Comment: @hege_hegedus it looks like **file:///C:/...Website/login.html?** the only difference is that it has a ?

Comment: @hege_hegedus is correct. Serve the file via a webserver.

Comment: @SpiderMonkey, do you see welcome alert or else alert message "Sorry Student". make sure !

Comment: @Venkatraman yes both alert messages come up!

Comment: then its triggered  2 times

Comment: Did anyone reproduce the problem?

Comment: @Venkatraman No both alerts don't come up at the same time. If the password matches the one in the local storage then the Welcome alert shows. If the password does not matches then the sorry alert appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You opened your html from the local filesystem. Although it seems to work at first glance, many features are disabled for security reasons. One of them might be page redirect.

I suggest you to grab some development webserver, and serve your files through that. See express or connect for nodejs, or the following for python:

- Navigate to the root of your webapp
- Run `python -m http.server` for python3, or `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` for python2
- Open `http://localhost:8000` in your browser

Most JavaScript and HTML IDE-s have some builtin serving functionality too.

Comment: Thank! However is there a way to by pass using a web server? Its for a school project, and its just has to be pretty simple.